# How to run the mongodb-rest?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I'm new to node, I followed the official guide on the [README file](https://github.com/tdegrunt/mongodb-rest), I believe the mongodb-rest is successfully installed, however npm shows:

```
npm ls
/usr/local/bin
(empty)
```

there's no mongodb-rest listed here

I simply don't know how to fire up the server as the guide says

```
 After that you can just issue mongodb-rest on the command line and the server should start.
```

I try `node mongodb-rest` or even type `mongodb-rest` in the node console, but either one works. 
Help!

Update--

Thanks to the people answer me question, I think I successfully installed the mongodb-rest package through npm, and start up the mongodb-rest server by type `mongodb-rest`, and make a http request in another terminal window by using curl as the README writes

```
curl -d '{ "A1" : 201 }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/test/example1
```

I got `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

and the message in the server console:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'authenticate' of null
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-rest/lib/rest.js:72:10
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-rest/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:176:16
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-rest/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:366:7)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:81:20)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-rest/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:97:15)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb-rest/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:399:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Array.<anonymous> (net.js:831:12)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

Comment: I have this same problem - any fix ever found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For npm to install a module globally, use the `-g` option. The readme for mongodb-rest failed to specify thata.

```
$ [sudo] npm -g install mongodb-rest
```

After, the command `mongodb-rest` should work.

BTW, to get a list of globally installed modules, add the `-g` option to the `ls` command too.

```
$ npm -g ls
```

Comment: After successfully install the mongodb-test, I type mongodb-rest in the terminal, nothing happen except a blinking prompt, Is it suggestion everything working?

Comment: Maybe that's how mongodb-rest works, I dunno. It didn't say "command not found".

Comment: Yes there's no 'command not found' prompt, Thanks anyway, I'm gonna figure it out myself